# How do I display a graph in root with Linux on chromebook?

Tags: ubuntu, c++, chrome-book, graph, cern-root

I am extremely new to Linux and I'm using the Chromebook's Linux beta which I believe is ubuntu. I'm trying to use CERN's root software to display a function's graph but it gives me a massive error when it tries to give me the actual graph. My syntax is correct I just don't know how to get the Chromebook to let Linux show me a graphic.

Here's the code I put in

```
f = new TF1("f","x^2",-2,2)
f->Draw()
```

and here's a link to the error message

https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/FyMb4yvB8X/

Root uses C++

If youre wondering how I installed ROOT I used this guide under 30.4

https://root.cern.ch/root/html534/guides/users-guide/InstallandBuild.html#installing-precompiled-binaries

I downloaded the ROOT prerequisites from this page

https://root.cern.ch/build-prerequisites

And then I used this to launch it

```
. <pathname>/root/bin/thisroot.sh
root
```

Comment: I believe from scratch, I downloaded the source off the site root.cern.ch/ and followed the install instructions. I didnt use any apt commands so I guess I did it from scratch.

Comment: I added the steps I did and the guide I used

Comment: Those binaries are pretty unsteady if they depend on some dynamic libs...maybe try the source install...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, install the following dependency:

```
sudo apt install libgif-dev
```

Now, run `root` and then run your commands. If you still get the same error, you need to download the [Ubuntu 18.04 version of CERN root from here](https://root.cern/download/root_v6.18.04.Linux-ubuntu18-x86_64-gcc7.4.tar.gz). This version is listed as "Ubuntu 18" on the [downloads page](https://root.cern.ch/content/release-61804).

---

**Here is the explanation:**

Your error says that you are missing the file: `libgif.so.4` . You can install `apt-file` to help you locate what package contains a file you are searching for.

First, install `apt-file`:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install apt-file
sudo apt-file update
```

Then, search for `libgif.so`:

```
apt-file search libgif.so
```

This should show you that the file `libgif.so.4` is provided by the package `libgif4`  or that the file `libgif.so.7` is provided by `libgif7`.

The package `libgif7` is available on Ubuntu Bionic (18.04) whereas `libgif4` is available on Ubuntu Xenial (16.04).

The "dev" package `libgif-dev` will install whatever version is available as a dependency (libgif4 or libgif7). However, the file listed in the error is the version for 16.04 so if you still get the error after installing `libgif-dev`, then you need to download the [version of CERN root](https://root.cern/download/root_v6.18.04.Linux-ubuntu18-x86_64-gcc7.4.tar.gz) that uses `libgif.so.7` (18.04 version) instead of `libgif.so.4`.

Comment: You can also search for package names using `apt-cache search` like in this example: `apt-cache search libgif`

Comment: Additionally, `apt-cache show` will show information about a package, including the dependencies that will also be installed, like in this example: `apt-cache show libgif-dev`